# Регулярное выражение для поиска data-атрибутов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Может найдутся гуру регулярок. Язык PHP. Не могу составить нормальную регулярку для поиска значений data- атрибутов в html документе.

Имена атрибутов заранее неизвестны, только начало data-... Например:

```
data-image="значение"
data-background="значение"
data-background-image="значение"
data-src="значение"
```

и т.д.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: вообще-то, существуют HTML парсеры, то же domDocument. Правильнее было бы им воспользоваться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/<\w+.*?\bdata\-(.+?)\s*=\s*(['"])(.*?)\2/
```

где:

- `<\w` - начало тега
- `.*?` - любые символы до начала data- атрибута
- `\b` - граница слова
- `data\-` собственно сам префикс
- `(.+?)` - имя атрибута
- `\s*=\s*` - знак равно, быть может, окруженный пробелами
- `(['"])` - открывающая кавычка или апостроф
- `(.*?)` - значение атрибута
- `\2` - закрывающая кавычка или апостроф. Причем закрывать должен тот же символ, что и открывал

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LhikcV/2)

Comment: Шикарная регулярка, но позанудствовать стоит =)
В результат будут ошибочно возвращены данные находящиеся вне тегов < >

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Поправил. Теги с кириллическими именами проверять не буду :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'data-image="значение"
data-background="значение"
data-background-image="значение"
data-src="значение"';

preg_match_all('~data[^"]+"\K[^"]+~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

---

[Демо PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/LIysZP/1)